# How do I specify one of possible return types?

Tags: rust

I have a function that returns one of two structs dependings on some logic. I need to specify the return type to be one of two. How do I do that?

```
struct A {}

struct B {}

fn picky() -> ??? {
    let a = A{};
    let b = B{};
    if 1 < 10 {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
}

fn main() {
    picky();
}
```

This feels like it should be trivial but after hours on Google I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function has only one return type, but this type may be an [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/enum.html):

```
struct A {}
struct B {}

enum AB {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}

fn picky() -> AB {
    let a = A{};
    let b = B{};
    if 1 < 10 {
        AB::A(a)
    } else {
        AB::B(b)
    }
}
```

That's exactly how [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) works in Rust: you get either the desired value or an error, because the result is an enum with two variants.

Comment: Some usage examples in playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=004ddc128b80a62785c11e59e834f0fe

Comment: @ilmoi If one of the two can be considered a normal return and the other an abnormal/error return, you can (ab)use `Result<A, B>` as the return type. There is also a crate that offers an [`Either` type](https://docs.rs/either/1.6.1/either/) where both types are on equal footing. If in doubt what to use, just create your own enum as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, the structs probably have something in common.

In this case I think it would be best to return a Boxed trait like so:

```rust
trait TraitForAandB {}

struct A {}
impl TraitForAandB for A {}

struct B {}
impl TraitForAandB for B {}

fn picky() -> Box<dyn TraitForAandB> {
    let a = A{};
    let b = B{};
    if 1 < 10 {
        Box::new(a)
    } else {
        Box::new(b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    picky();
}
```

Playground is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=349e2b8f93ac3ad7d787d58a156d7c6a).